# start service by sendBroadcast or startService

Tags: android, service, intentfilter

i have a service like this below

```
<service
        android:name="com.example.s.SilenterService"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.s.Object.Actions.LOCATION_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="com.example.s.Object.Actions.RENEW_CHECKING" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

i want to handle these two intents in my service.

how should i call my service now from another places (i have some activities and some broadcastreceivers)

how should i start my service??

like this

```
Intent silenterService = new Intent(context, SilenterService.class);
silenterService.setAction(DefaultActivity.fullname(Actions.RENEW_CHECKING));
context.startService(silenterService);
```

or like this?

```
Intent silenterService = new Intent(DefaultActivity.fullname(Actions.RENEW_CHECKING));
context.sendBroadcast(silenterService);
```

thanks a lot for any helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `startService`. `sendBroadcast` is intended for `BroadcastReceivers`.